# Contour label rotation wrong when using manual positioning

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am adding label at certain positions on a contour plot in matplotlib.
As describe in the documentaion, when using the `manual=true` parameter, I can place the label and everything seems fine (see 1st plot below) but when entering the possitions of those labels in the code directly as `manual=[(x0,y0), (x1,y1), etc.]` the rotation of the labels seems to go wrong for some reason (2nd plot).
[image]

I can't figure out why it not the same behavior in both cases unlike what is mentionned in the documentation or is it a bug?

[Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/contour_api.html#matplotlib.contour.ContourLabeler.clabel)

> manual can also be an iterable object of (x, y) tuples. Contour labels will be created as if mouse is clicked at each (x, y) position.

Here is the code to generate it. Note on the bottom `manual=True` or `manual=positions`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


delta = 0.01
x = np.arange(75, 300+delta, delta)
y = np.arange(1.75, 4.01, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X*Y

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
levels = [150, 250, 300, 350, 450, 500, 550, 650, 700, 750, 850, 900, 950, 1050, 1100, 1150]
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=levels, colors='k', linewidths=0.1)
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 5, colors='k', linewidths=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel("Capacity (mAh/g)", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel(r'Average voltage (V vs. ${Li^{+}/Li}$)', fontsize=12)

# Square graph
aspect = (x.max()-x.min())/(y.max()-y.min())
ax.set_aspect(aspect)

plt.tight_layout()

positions = [(94,2.122), (157,2.54), (206,2.915), (244,3.29), (273,3.66)]
ax.clabel(CS, inline=True, fontsize=12, fmt='%1.f Wh/kg', manual=True) # or manual=positions

plt.show()
```

Comment: Force a draw to make sure the aspect is applied before the clabel starts.  With modern matplotlib: fig.draw_without_rendering()

Comment: Had to update matplotlib to 3.5.1 but worked perfectly Thanks!

Comment: Fig.canvas.draw() should work too.

Comment: @JodyKlymak what is the difference between fig.draw_without_rendering and fig.canvas.draw? Shall I ask this as a question that you can answer?

Comment: I’m not sure to be honest.  There are some slight interactive differences that I don’t understand but basically if you want to force a draw draw_without_rendering is the (new) proper way with (supposedly) fewer side effects.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I see. I assumed that the new version might be faster but point taken.